# 'abp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: abp

I just started exploring the Abp features, I created a sample project from their website and able to build the project successfully. But When I run the dbmigrator project getting an exception,
Below is the screenshot of the error,

[image]

I followed this article to run the app

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Running-Solution?UI=MVC&DB=EF&Tiered=No

Do we need to install any additional package to make it work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are missing the `abp` cli.

`dotnet tool install -g Volo.Abp.Cli`

Just install it using the above command and try again in a new prompt. it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure about abp.cli is already installed, you can run the command using by abp.exe file path like this:

```
C:\Users\username\.dotnet\tools\abp.exe new Acme.BookStore
```

Answer (score 0):

My antivirus deleted the abp.exe and I restored it from the quarantine